# How to modify timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem modifying timestamp. I have tried several things, with no successful result.

I have this code, and I want the timestamp to be like this: 14. december, 2013.

```
<?php
            $sql = "
                SELECT
                    `news`.`headline` AS `title`,
                    `news`.`timestamp` AS `time`
                FROM `news`
                ORDER BY `news`.`id` DESC LIMIT 4
            ";
            $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo '<div class="newsbox">
                        <div class="newsimage">
                            <img src="upload/'.$row['link'].'" style="width:211px;height:130px" />
                        </div><!--newsimage-->
                      <div class="newstext">
                        <span class="timestamp">
                            <p>'.$row['time'].'</p>
                        </span><!--timestamp-->
                        <span class="headline">
                            <h1>'.$row['title'].'</h1>
                        </span><!--headline-->  
                    </div>
                    </div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Where should I add the dateformat?

Comment: There an `UPDATE` statement in there someplace? Oh, modify as in *format*.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this in your sql?

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('news.timestamp'), '%e %b %Y') AS `time`
```

Comment: Uh, thanks. That seems to work. But now, (yes, I'm not that good yet, sorry) it the date is the 1 january 1970. Why isn't it showing the date thats in the row in the database?

Comment: ok nice that it helped you ! if this answer what u want make sure to accept it to help others .

Comment: Yes i will. But when i tried, it said that I had to wait 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

with replace this

```
 <p>'.date("j, F ,Y",$row['time']).'</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a unix timestamp...

Put this inside the while loop:

```
$new_date = date('j, F, Y', $row['time']);
```

You should checkout this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php